# Is there a method like Android's Finish() in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a method that will end the previous pages/activities as I navigate through different pages so that when the back button is pressed it does not navigate back to that previous message. In Java Android such a method is called finish(), so is there such a method in Xamarin Cross Platform?

Comment: WPF and Xamarin are completely different technologies, please do not mix them.

Comment: Did you not even google for it ? [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.Finish/)

Comment: @Vucko I did and if you check correctly I didn't ask about Xamarin Android

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Forms has some options to remove from or add pages to the stack. Take a look at `Navigation.PopAsync` or `Navigation.RemovePage`.

Answer (score 0):

On **Xamarin Form for Android**, you have a similar method for that: [Finish](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.Finish/)();

I think you are finding this method?

Comment: Not xamarin for android, I am using portable class

Comment: if you are using portable class, then it means you propably have your own navigation service. Just make your ViewModels implement IDisposable and add a method NavigateAndReset to your nav service, which clears the stack and disposes ViewModels. That's all

Answer (score 0):

There's no method finish in xamarin forms because finish() is to let the system know that the programmer wants the current Activity to be finished. In xamarin forms you only have one Activity which is MainActivity. Xamarin forms revolves around Navigation, So if you want to go back to previous navigation Navigation.PopAsync or if you want to close a modal use Navigation.PopModal

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you described your objective, I think `this.Finish();` will work like a charm.

**Example Code:**

```
Button nextPage;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.your_content_xml);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

            nextPage = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

            nextPage.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(next_page_CS_file)); // Create Intent instance
                StartActivity(nextActivity); // Go to the Next Page as set in Intent
                this.Finish(); // Terminates Current Page.
                               // As such, once you're in the next page, clicking the back button 
                               // on phone's menu will close the App instead of going back here
            };
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Any code you want that'll handle the Exception.
            // Like, for example, . . .
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

From my understanding and experience, this should work. However I'm unsure if there are other ways of accomplishing what you aim for.